# What Are the Percentage Markings on this Stormwater Management Drawing?

Tags: landscaping, engineering

We purchased a house in Arlington Co, Virginia, and there is a "Micro-bioretention facility" in the middle of the backyard, making the back yard almost useless for enjoyment. In order to move or substitute that facility with something less obtrusive, we need to submit to the county for approval, and the cost to have an engineer do it is on the order of $6,000 (which doesn't include any construction costs).

So, it seems worth at least trying to submit a proposal without the assistance of an engineer. Here is part of the diagram for the existing system, and I'm unsure what the percentages are (circled in red). I understand that `12' L.F. 4" PVC` means twelve linear feet of 4" diameter PVC. Does the `@0.8%` indicate the slope? Surely the slope would be more than 1%, right? Does it mean something else?

[image]

Comment: The slope looks like .8 and 1.8 to me remember that 90 is straight down.

Comment: The @0.8% and the @1.8% are the slope of the lines.  It's not necessary that these slope 1%.  What's important is that the slope coupled with the size of the line are adequate to provide the required flow.  But I think you'll find that submitting plans without an engineer's stamp will not be acceptable to the county.

Comment: In my town the requirement for licensed professionals to participate in preliminary applications is sometimes overlooked when the application is for something very minor and doesn't depart too much from existing drawings.   If your town is like mine, and you're planning to completely re-do this, they'll probably want a pro involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - those are slopes. There is no need to exceed 1% since depending on peak flow and pipe diameter you can achieve sufficient flow at less than 1%. You are of course right that practically speaking the difference between a very small slope and zero becomes sometimes hard to maintain and you could end up with a low spot.

Numerically, you are looking at about 1 1/8 inches fall for the 12' pipe (@0.8%) and about 2 3/8 inches fall for the 11' pipe (@1.8%). These figures are not in degrees contrary to some of the comments.

Regarding your permit issue, I can feel your pain. Especially, if the experts you are forced to hire submit drawings with typos and possibly other mistakes. ('Biotention'? I can feel some tension ...)

Can you get away with modifying the micro-bioretention facility so that it allows your backyard fun but doesn't trigger the permitting process?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to modify it without triggering the permitting process. Our county has an easement on the property, and we are required to submit maintenance records and photos each year. There are some ways to cheat, but that doesn't align with my ethical character.